# Conditional probability with a temporal feature

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

My probability skills are quite rusty and I'm becoming stuck with a text mining problem that requires knowing the conditional probability of a word's co-occurrence.

To be more specific, say I have two speakers having a back-and-forth conversation, I want to determine the conditional probability of Alice using a word *w* given that it had been spoken by Bob in **the** previous utterance, not **a** previous utterance. Consider the below, with the word 'one':

Bob: One fish, Two fish, Red fish, Blue fish,

Alice: Black fish, Blue fish, Old fish, New fish.

Bob: This one has a little car.

Alice: This one has a little star.

Using a binary variable (where 1 = the presence of the word in the sentence, and 0 means the absence of the word in the sentence), I have gotten as far as deducing that the probability of Alice using the word 'one' is 1/2 (because she has two utterances, one of which contains the word I am looking for), and the probability of Bob using the word is 2/2 (because he has two utterances, both of which contain the word I am looking for) - Although crucially, only one corresponds with Alice using the word in an immediate reply.

Intuitively, I am assuming that the way to resolve this is to count the number of times Bob says the word I am looking for as the denominator, and to count the number of successes (Alice immediately repeating the word) as the numerator. This makes sense and, i think, corresponds with the definition for a conditional probability (as I am narrowing the sample space) - but as I have arrived at it atheoretically I am a little unsure if it is correct.

Comment: I would be counting the set of words, so each word would be limited to 0 (if absent from utterance) or 1 (if present in utterance, irrespective of quantity).

Comment: That sounds right, and you count "Alice immediately repeating the word," so "blue" doesn't count in this example, although it would have counted it Bob had said it first?

Comment: That's it yes, although in that case blue would be counted as it was mentioned by Bob in the first post. But, your example works for words such as 'old' or 'new' as these were introduced to the conversation by Alice, not Bob - Thanks for the clarification David, I was trying to stick to instructions provided in online tutorials, but almost all of them either give you the probability of the intersection, or the inverse conditional probability.

Comment: Right, I chose the wrong word as an example. Technically each pair of utterances (Bob then Alice) is a trial and each time you count Alice’s word you’re counting an intersection of the events “Bob said it” and “Alice said it.”